# Input impedance of IGBT and power MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, impedance, igbt

Between IGBTs and power MOSFETs, which has greater input impedance/resistance? (This is a question I was asked during an interview.)

Comment: Well, they both have insulated gates, so at DC they would be similar. The gate sizes would differ between igbts and mosfets of similar ratings, so at AC they would appear different. Do some research and determine the differences. A good engineer does not know everything, but he knows how to learn.

Comment: Both have insulated gates, and both have input impedances that will be dominated by the Miller effect when switching. So maybe you ought to look at the inter-terminal capacitance when comparing devices of like current rating.

Comment: *This is a question I was asked during an interview* When I do interviews I would ask more advanced questions like: How would you measure the input impedance? Which device is easier to drive in which circumstances? Questions that simply test if you know something or not are not so relevant and do not show what **skills** you have.